# Sync Adapter and SQLite instance

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I've created custom `syncAdapter` for my Android app. Also I've created `Sqlite` helper that is a singleton.

Next, when I'm trying to login I'm creating a helper instance and it works ok. But after login when i want to call `SyncAdapter` method `onPerformSync()` new instance of helper is created.

Helper:

```
public static DBHelper getInstance(Context context){
    if(instance == null){
        instance = new DBHelper (context, "DBName");
    }
    return instance;
}
```

onPerformSync():

```
@Override
public void onPerformSync(Account account, Bundle extras, String authority, ContentProviderClient provider, SyncResult syncResult) {
        helper = DBHelper .getInstance(context);
}
```

Anyone can help?

Comment: I think that this can happen only if your `getInstance` is called from two (or more) different threads. Try to synchronize the access to `getInstance()` method, declaring it as `public static synchronized DBHelper getInstance()`

Comment: I tried that, didnt work

Comment: Are you sure that you have two instances of the DBHelper class?

Comment: Yeah, when I'm debugging two instances are created

Comment: I think that this is not possibile! http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/05/correctly-managing-your-sqlite-database.html